# Python Flask - Passing hash input in API call

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api, flask

I am a beginner in making API. I have followed the blog https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask and able to create the Get - Post API method.

I am using Flask to making Rest API. Please see the code below in which I want to take question as input in API and return an answer in JSON format by making my code as an API.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/match/api/v1', methods = ['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if not request.json or not 'question' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    input_text_p = request.json['question'] # access input from curl request
    reference_data = request.json['data'] # to access data field from the API            request
    path = 'airtel_faq.xlsx'
    question_list, answer_list = read_excel_file(path) # reading some     reference data from an excel file
    input_text = input_text_p.translate(None, string.punctuation) # remove punctuation

    final_answer = find_similarity(input_text, answer_list, question_list)
    print "Final Answer is : ", final_answer

    values = [
        {'id' : 1,
         'answer' : final_answer # answer I want in JSON
         'done' : False
        }
    ]
    return jsonify({'values': values}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug = True)
```

I am trying to pass hash input for data tag in the request to API. I am not aware how to do this. The curl request I am making is giving error:

```
Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting ',' delimiter or '}': line 1 column 80 (char 79)
```

The curl request I am making :

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"question":"Hi","cutoff":"0.3", "data":"{"q":"hello whats going on","a":"I am fine","type":"1"}"}' http://localhost:5000/match/api
```

Please let me know how to do this. Do I have to include anything in my script. Or is there a way to pass the JSON file in API call by giving path to the file.

Comment: where is the hash?

Comment: @stamaimer, "data":"{"q":"hello whats going on","a":"I am fine","type":"1"}"

I am talking about this hash input.. This will have multiple fields, for now I have taken only one question and answer pair in data.

Comment: You are missing delimiter `,` after `'answer' : final_answer`

Comment: Also data is not in json format. You do not need `"` before `{` and after `}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the JSON request, it needs to be valid JSON.  Try this request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"question": "Hi", "cutoff": "0.3", "data": {"q": "hello whats going on", "a": "I am fine", "type": "1"}}' http://localhost:5000/match/api
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I figured it out :)